# Cmd.exe default registry keys

Tags: windows-registry, cmd.exe

My `cmd.exe` registry settings are messed up for font, size, etc. Could someone tell me the default values or give a link to `.reg` file that will restore these settings? I tried looking for this on the Internet but I didn't really find anything.

Comment: What do you mean by “cmd.exe registry files”?

Comment: HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console

Comment: I see. And lastly, which Windows version are we talking about?

Comment: We are talking about  windows 7

Comment: This work has been done by others here http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/19449-default-file-type-associations-restore.html , download the linked registry, open it in a notepad to see what is going on, and have a backup, then your all set.

Comment: I think windows version doesn't really matter guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Default CMD session settings are stored here:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console
```

You can just delete `Console` registry key. `cmd.exe` will re-create it with default values (probably from `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Console`, but im not sure).

It is good habit to backup registry key before deleting.

You can also create new Windows user and export default values to compare them with your messed up settings to fix only some settings.